ef core: unidirectional many-to-many relationships
EF Core beginner here, so please be patient. We're trying to migrate an existing app from NHibernate to EF Core and we're facing several interesting issues. One of them is related with unidirectional many-to-many relationships.
According to the docs, EF supports unidirection many-to-many relationships. Unfortunately, I'm having some issues when trying to configure it. Here's a snippet that presents the classes we need to map into tables:
// this is the class that has the reference to the other entity
public class GuiaAbate : Entity 
{
    private IList<Equipamento> _equipamentos = new List<Equipamento>( );

  // other properties/methods removed

   // unidirectional navigation to many
   public IEnumerable<Equipamento> Equipamentos {
        get => new ReadOnlyCollectionBuilder<Equipamento>(_equipamentos);
        internal set => _equipamentos = value.ToList( );
    }

}

// even though I believe it's not that important, here's the other class
// this is an abstract class since there are several derived classes
// for this type, all derived types are mapped to the same table
public abstract class Equipamento : Entity, IVersionamento 
{
  // it has some properties and collections which reference other entiites
  // however, there's nothing point back to GuiaAbate (ie, no IEnumerable<GuiaAbate> prop)
  // because we're only interested in the other side of the navigation
}

We can't change the database tables, so here's what it looks like now:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GuiaAbate](
    [IDGuiaAbate] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Data] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Login] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LoginAD] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_GuiaAbate] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDGuiaAbate] ASC
) ) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Equipamento](
    [IDEquipamento] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    /* other fields removed */ 

 CONSTRAINT [PK_Equipamento] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDEquipamento] ASC
)) ON [PRIMARY]



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GuiaAbateEquipamento](
    [IDGuiaAbateEquipamento] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IDGuiaAbate] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDEquipamento] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_GuiaAbateEquipamento] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDGuiaAbateEquipamento] ASC
)) ON [PRIMARY]


As you can see, nothing too fancy.
Now, since I can't reuse the default conventions, I've tried the following mappings for the GuiaAbate type:
public sealed class GuiaAbateTypeConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<GuiaAbate> 
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<GuiaAbate> builder) 
    {
        builder.ToTable("GuiaAbate");

        builder.HasKey(g => g.Id);
        builder.Property(g => g.Id).HasColumnName("IdGuiaAbate");

        builder.Property(g => g.Data)
               .HasConversion(d => d,
                              d => new DateTime(d.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc));

        builder.Property(g => g.Data)
               .HasConversion(
                   d => d,
                   d => new DateTime(d.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc));
        builder.Property(g => g.Tecnico).HasColumnName("Login");

        builder.HasMany(g => g.Equipamentos)
               .WithMany( )
               .UsingEntity(
                   "GuiaAbateEquipamento",
                   r => r.HasOne(typeof( Equipamento )).WithMany( ).HasForeignKey("IdEquipamento"),
                   l => l.HasOne(typeof( GuiaAbate )).WithMany( ).HasForeignKey("IdGuiaAbate"));
    }
}

The idea is to specify the name of the join table and the name of the columns that should be used as foreign keys on that table. Unfortunately, I must be missing something here because I end up with an error that says that
The skip navigation 'Equipamento.GuiaTransporte' doesn't have a foreign key associated with it. Every skip navigation must have a configured foreign key.

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

After trying everything, I've noticed that the error was on the GuiaTransporte mapping and not on the GuiaAbate. Anyway, the issue was on the configure left vs right lambdas: swapping them solved the problem (btw, the snippet I've shown for `GuiaAbate´ does work without any issues).

You have a table
GuiaAbateEquipamento
and while you have the 2 "FK" columns on this table....
you also have
IDGuiaAbateEquipamento
while it may seem trivial, this is a "property ON THE RELATIONSHIP".
..
Thus you need a third entity your design.. that captures the RELATIONSHIP.
I am going to show a generic example.
public partial class EmployeeEntity
{
    public long EmployeeKey { get; set; } /* PK */


    public string LastName { get; set; }


    /* Navigation */
    
    public ICollection<EmployeeToJobTitleLinkEntity> EmployeeToJobTitleLinks { get; set; } = new List<EmployeeToJobTitleLinkEntity>();

}

and
public partial class JobTitleEntity
{
    public long JobTitleKey { get; init; } /* PK */
      
    public string JobTitleName { get; init; }
      
    public string JobTitleDescription { get; init; }
      

    /* Navigation */
    public ICollection<EmployeeToJobTitleLinkEntity> EmployeeToJobTitleLinks { get; set; } = new List<EmployeeToJobTitleLinkEntity>();

}

and
public class EmployeeToJobTitleLinkEntity
{
    public long EmployeeToJobTitleLinkKey { get; set; } /* PK */
    
    public long EmployeeKey { get; set; } /* FK as scalar (long) */
    
    public long JobTitleKey { get; set; } /* FK  as scalar (long) */
    

    /* navigation properties */
    public EmployeeEntity Employee { get; set; }

    public JobTitleEntity JobTitle { get; set; }


}

Note, that I have a dedicated "EntityObject" (EmployeeToJobTitleLinkEntity in my generic example), that handles the RELATIONSHIP.
Here is the "Map".  (I use Fluent).
The "EmployeeMap" (not shown) and the "JobTitleMap" are trivial, just as you would expect.
The more significant map is seen below.
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

public class EmployeeToJobTitleLinkMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<EmployeeToJobTitleLinkEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EmployeeToJobTitleLinkEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("EmployeeToJobTitleLink", "dbo");

        builder.HasKey(k => k.EmployeeToJobTitleLinkKey);
        builder.Property(cn => cn.EmployeeToJobTitleLinkKey)
            .HasColumnName("EmployeeToJobTitleLinkKey");
        builder.Property(req => req.EmployeeToJobTitleLinkKey).IsRequired();

        builder.Property(cn => cn.EmployeeKey).HasColumnName("EmployeeKey");
        builder.Property(req => req.EmployeeKey).IsRequired();

        builder.Property(cn => cn.JobTitleKey).HasColumnName("JobTitleKey");
        builder.Property(req => req.JobTitleKey).IsRequired();



        builder.HasOne(ent => ent.Employee)
            .WithMany(c => c.EmployeeToJobTitleLinks)
            .HasForeignKey(chd => chd.EmployeeKey)
            .HasConstraintName(
                "Your_Custom_Name_1");


        builder.HasOne(ent => ent.JobTitle)
            .WithMany(c => c.EmployeeToJobTitleLinks)
            .HasForeignKey(chd => chd.JobTitleKey)
            .HasConstraintName("Your_Custom_Name_2");
    }
}

The "issue" (IMHO) is that all the learning sites.
for example:
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration
do not distinguish between the "trivial M:N" and the "non-trivial, PROPERTY ON THE RELATIONSHIP" M:N.
...
While you only have a designated PK column on your "link" table, it is a property of the relationship.
In my generic example... imagine you wanted to add an extra property on the RELATIONSHIP.
"EmployeeStartedThisJobTitleDateOf".
"Jose" started as a Developer ON Jan 1, 2020.
"Jose" started as a Architect ON Sept 2, 2021.
"Maria" started as a Developer ON Feb 28, 2022.
"Maria" started as a Architect ON July 14, 2023.
this "start-date" is not a value of the employee.  it is not a value on the job-title.
It is a value ON THE RELATIONSHIP of the M:N.
..
Now, you may be tempted to just ignore the PK column on the link table....but this does "paint you into a corner" for a major refactoring down the road if you want to add a new column to the link-table.
Thus, 99% of the time, I just go ahead and code the original version to the "advanced "M:N" setup".
